# Pasar datos de un fichero a una estructura en C

Tags: c, string, archivo, struct

Tengo un fichero .txt tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde cada campo separado por ' / ' representa una característica diferente de un producto, en concreto:

ID / Descripción / ID de la categoría / ID del proveedor / Stock / Dias hasta entrega / Precio

He pensado que la estructura mas correcta sería algo así:

```
typedef struct {
int *IDp;
char *Nombre;
int *Catg;
int *Prov;
int *Stock;
int *Dias;
int *Precio; }productos;
```

Uso punteros para poder reservar dinámicamente cada campo.
Las dudas surgen a la hora de tratar los números como int o como char, y por supuesto leer el fichero para inicializar la estructura.
He pensado en usar fgets para leer cada linea y recorrer el string separando los campos, pero no se como hacer que lea cada bloque separando ' / '.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta ?

Comment: La estructura no debería tener nombre en plural, pues contiene un solo dato no una colección de datos.

Comment: Tengo que desarrollar un programa que funcione como una tienda online estilo Amazon, esta duda es parte de la gestion de los productos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He pensado en usar fgets para leer cada linea y recorrer el string separando los campos

Muy buen comienzo, es exactamente lo que tienes que hacer.

> no se cómo hacer que lea cada bloque separando ' / '

El proceso que describes se conoce como *tokenización* y la cabecera `<string.h>` dispone de una función para ese fin: [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char texto[] = "000001/televisor 32\" 3D7001/0001/50/5/340";

    for (char *palabra = strtok(texto, "/"); palabra; palabra = strtok(NULL, "/"))
        printf("%s\n", palabra);

    return 0;
}
```

El [código anterior](https://tio.run/##TY4/D4IwFMRn@ileakyoQUGROKBOjsTNSRxqKdCILSmFmBg/OwL@fdPL3S93x6asoDJr25GQrKgTDuvKJELN8i36l7SQWa8hIQ1cqZB2o0RC0B1ZLKcaDL8ZdTzBBrDX39w1vOCNqJQGfxFj8HerXh2swHMD1196OETISjvCHjImJS3oWdMupCs06mIPqQ5gF5MQ3u73@WH7QxS9KIIsq@y2mtTG4yqW2PnQpO/S3NRagheiR9s@AQ) genera la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 000001
> televisor 32" 3D7001
> 0001
> 50
> 5
> 340
> ```

Dicho eso, atendamos tu duda:

> Las dudas surgen a la hora de tratar los números como int o como char

Para decidir eso debes responder las siguientes preguntas:

- ¿Los campos son activos (tras leer los datos se debe operar sobre ellos)?.
- Las operaciones sobre los campos activos ¿Son aritméticas?

Si la respuesta a ambas preguntas es afirmativa, lo que necesitas es un campo numérico (`int`).

Comment: No conocía el comando strtok, la verdad es que parece muy útil, pero no termino de entender como la salida que general puede ser introducida en la estructura. Respecto a lo de los numeros, estos campos serán usados para relacionarse con otras estructuras para poder realizar búsquedas y cosas similares

Comment: Tu pregunta era: 1) "*¿leer el fichero para inicializar la estructura con `fgets`?*" la respuesta es si. 2) Tokenizar: usa `strtok`. 3) `char` o `int`: depende. Si tienes alguna duda más, te animo a hacer una pregunta nueva.